# Conflicting group IDs ubuntu 14.04 software update -- dpkg error

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, dpkg, groups

Today I tried to update the linux on my cluster nodes. After running `apt-get upgrade` as root, I got this error:

```
Setting up passwd (1:4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9.2) ...
groupadd: GID '42' already exists
Group ID 42 has been allocated for the shadow group.  You have either
used 42 yourself or created a shadow group with a different ID.
Please correct this problem and reconfigure with dpkg --configure passwd''.

Note that both user and group IDs in the range 0-99 are globally
allocated by the Debian project and must be the same on every Debian
system.
dpkg: error processing package passwd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I typed `less /etc/group`, I noticed that gdm is listed with 42 ID.

I must mention that my cluster is a bit special. Because I'm not allowed to touch the main node, I have an older version of Scientific Linux on it and ubuntu 14.04 on my nodes. When we add new users, I just copy `group`, `passwd` and `shadow` from the main node on my nodes. This was fine up to now, but now I'm wondering what did I mess up to get this error. Unfortunately, I forgot to back up the `group`, `passwd` and `shadow` files.

Comment: Not an answer, but I backed up the `group`, `passwd`, `shadow` files and edited out the lines containing `gdm` from them and then the updates proceeded as expected.